# How to change the callout left accessory image view dynamically based on json response

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am trying to dynamically change the callout image based on json response.But only one image display for all callouts please help me how to do this

```
#pragma mark Map View Delegate Methods
```

method for view for annotation
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation
    {
        // If it's the user location, just return nil.
        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
            return nil;

```
    // Handle any custom annotations.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]])
    {
        // Try to dequeue an existing pin view first.
        MKAnnotationView *pinView = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
        if (!pinView)
        {
            // If an existing pin view was not available, create one.
            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
            pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"];
            pinView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 30);
            pinView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 32);

            // Add a detail disclosure button to the callout.
            UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", islandArray); // print

            //to display a island image in callout view


            UIImageView *calloutImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

            NSLog(@"%@",[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"mapImage"]]);

            calloutImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"mapImage"]]]];

            calloutImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 30, 30);
            [calloutImage.layer setCornerRadius:05.0f];
            pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = calloutImage;
            pinView.tintColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

        }
        else
        {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        return pinView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: The image url is being read from NSUserDefaults.  Is that being set as you create the annotations?  That is most likely the issue (and only setting the callout image when creating a view is another problem).  Show the code that creates the annotations (edit your question and add the code).